# How to scroll bottom container which has max-height defined?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have to scroll bottom container which has only max-height defined.
I try use **scrollTop = scrollHeight** but it does't work for me ?

Please advice

**My container (HTML/JSX):**

```
<div>  
  <ListElement />
  <ListElement />
  <ListElement />
  <ListElement />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
display: flex;
max-height: 400px
```

**Expected result**

Container always scrolled to bottom when the component appear.

**Similar solution**

```
container.scrollTop = contentHeight - containerHeight;
```

but above solution working fine only with defined height not max-height ;/

Comment: Please can you add some code to explain?

Comment: @Ale_info code is up

Answer (score 0):

Try `container.scrollTo(0, container.scrollHeight)`

Comment: the same effect, div is not scrolled to bottom